# How To Do Ruby on Rails link_to with a method in a controller

Tags: routes, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-1.9.3

I am using bcrypt-ruby for password encryption.  In the documentation for the gem http://bcrypt-ruby.rubyforge.org/ they give an action to allow someone to reset their password.  I am trying to implement this action.

I added the following code on my login page:

```
<p>Forgot your Password? <%= link_to "Click to reset your password", forgot_password_session_path, confirm: "Do you really want to reset your password?" %></p>
```

Here is the code in my sessions_controller.rb file:

```
def forgot_password
  random_password = Array.new(10).map { (65 + rand(58)).chr }.join
  case
    when User.find_by_email(params[:session][:email_user])
      user = User.find_by_email(params[:session][:email_user])
    when User.find_by_username(params[:session][:email_user])
      user = User.find_by_username(params[:session][:email_user])
  end  
  user.password = user.password_confirmation = random_password
  user.save!
  Mailer.create_and_deliver_password_change(user, random_password)
end
```

Here is the definition in config/routes.db:

```
resources :sessions do
  member do
    get "forgot_password"
  end
end
```

Here is the output from rake routes:

```
forgot_password_session GET    /sessions/:id/forgot_password(.:format) sessions#forgot_password
```

When I try to click on the link on my login link I get the following error:

No route matches {:action=>"forgot_password", :controller=>"sessions"}

I do not know how it says no route matches when it appears that it does.  I have restarted my rails server & spork but still get the error.  I do not know the next step.

Any help will be appreciated.

Update 5/26/2012 9:14 am GMT-6:

I changed to POST, restarted my rails server & Spork.  I got the same error.  Here is my log from the server:

Started GET "/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-05-26 09:13:36 -0500
Processing by SessionsController#new as HTML
  Rendered sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (112.4ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 116ms

Here is the rake routes info:

```
forgot_password_session POST   /sessions/:id/forgot_password(.:format) sessions#forgot_password
```

Answer (score 0):

It may need to be a POST request. When I took a rails class, putting inline link calls was inconsistant. The reason you have that error is that your routes file is configured for a GET, not a POST. Just a shot in the dark, but try adding the same line but with a POST.

Comment: I tried again but it did not work.  I updated my description with more information.  Looks like more code or maybe a changed setting somewhere is needed.

Comment: I took another look at the rake routes statement.  It looks like it is looking for a sessions/id/forgot_password path.  

I have the link on the login page.  There is no session id at that point since the login button has not been clicked.  I will move the procedure to application_controller.rb and pass the email or username to it and try again.  I will post an update with my results.

Comment: Sorry, it didn't help... when in doubt scaffold!? i don't really know, sorry.

Comment: No problem.  I will revisit this at another time.  I have a few more tasks for this project that I will attempt.  At least I am gaining more knowledge.  Thanks so much.